# add gitlab repository to redmine

Tags: git, ubuntu, redmine, gitlab

I'm try add a gitlab repository to redmine, but when accessing the repository via redmine, this displays the following message:

> "The entry or revision was not found in the repository."

My repo configuration:

[image]

**redmine:** 2.4.1
**OS:** ubuntu

### edit:

**test of www-data permissions:**

```
root@Development:~# su www-data
$  ls /home/git/repositories/mapb_1990/test.git/
branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs
```

Comment: Does the process running Redmine have permission to access that git repo? For example, if you're serving Redmine with Apache, does the apache/httpd user have permission to your git repo directory in the filesystem?

Comment: yes. I run a ls cmd with www-data user to the repos, and run without problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Passenger module for Apache chances are it might be running under `nobody` user (and not `www-data`).
Check out with:

```
root@Development:~# ps auxf | grep -A 8 -e "/usr/sbin/apache2 -k star[t]" -e /usr/local/share/redmin[e]
```

and look for processes starting with *Passenger* and *Rack*: are they running under `nobody` (I had the exact same issue and fixed it now so I can't check what exact output you should have).

(Redmine is located at */usr/local/share/redmine* in my setup).

And, in default setup, `nobody` cannot access to */home/git/repositories/*:

```
root@Development:~# su nobody
sh-4.2$ ls /home/git/repositories/
ls: cannot access /home/git/repositories/: Permission denied
```

You have two options:

- Makes path to "/home/git/repositories/mapb_1990/test.git/" available to all (`chmod -R o=rx /home/git/repositories/mapb_1990/test.git/`)
- Change Passenger use and group in VirtualHost configuration by adding following lines to your VirtualHost file:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
      PassengerUser www-data
      PassengerGroup www-data
  </IfModule>
  ```

  You might also want to run theses commands to make sure previously `nobody:nogroup` owned files are transfered to `www-data:www-data`:

  ```
  root@Development:~# find /usr/local/share/redmine -user nobody -exec chown www-data {} \;
  root@Development:~# find /usr/local/share/redmine -group nogroup -exec chgrp www-data {} \;
  ```

  And restart Apache:

  ```
  root@Development:~# service apache2 restart
  ```